# Rationale for small sample leads to larger effect sizes

Tags: sample-size, effect-size, small-sample

I was recently attending a seminar where the speaker mentioned something on the lines of:

> Here's a statistical fallacy...smaller sample sizes will lead to
> larger effect sizes

However, the speaker did not elaborate any further and there was no opportunity to follow up on it.

Could someone explain the idea behind this fallacy?

Comment: Whether it's a fallacy depends on how "effect sizes" is interpreted!

Comment: In all likelihood he was talking about Cohen's d and Hedges' g (because he later referred to these two, when presenting some of his results)

Comment: My point is that "effect size" may refer either to a *population parameter* (in which case the statement obviously is a fallacy, because the sample size cannot affect the parameter) or an *estimate.*  In the latter case, "Cohen's d" is just another name for something that is a multiple of the Student t statistic.  That's why the answer depends on how one understands the meaning of "effect size."

Comment: Ah I see! This was definitely in the estimate sense!

Comment: Then the quotation is (obviously) incorrect.  I therefore suspect it intended the meaning in the parameter sense.

Comment: @whuber: It can also mean in the sense of *conditioned on being significant*

Comment: @Kjetil When you condition on significance, the result is close to trivial: we all know that larger sample sizes create the possibility of detecting smaller effects, so that with small sample sizes typically only large "significant" effects will be reported.  But the statement is true even without conditioning on significance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see it as a fallacy, but I think I know what the speaker meant.

As the sample size increases, less effect size is demanded in order to reject at the $0.05$-level (or whatever level is desired). Therefore, if you are able to get a significant result with a small sample size, the observed effect size must be large. On the other hand, if the sample size is large, we can reject with just a small observed effect size.

```
library(ggplot2)
N1 <- 10
N2 <- 100
B <- 1000
e1 <- e2 <- rep(NA, B)
for (i in 1:B){
    
    x1 <- rnorm(N1, 0, 1)
    y1 <- rnorm(N1, 0.1, 1)
    
    x2 <- rnorm(N2, 0, 1)
    y2 <- rnorm(N2, 0.1, 1)
    
    # Screen for a "significant" t-test at the 0.05-level
    #
    if (t.test(x1, y1, var.equal = T)$p.value < 0.05){
    e1[i] <- abs(mean(x1) - mean(y1))
}
if (t.test(x2, y2, var.equal = T)$p.value < 0.05){
        e2[i] <- abs(mean(x2) - mean(y2))
    }
}

# Remove the NAs
#
e1 <- e1[is.na(e1) == F]
e2 <- e2[is.na(e2) == F]

# Put into a data frame and plot
#
d1 <- data.frame(effect = e1, sample = "Small")
d2 <- data.frame(effect = e2, sample = "Large")
d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = effect, fill = sample)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
    theme_bw()
```

The observed effect size magnitude for the small sample size is much larger than for the large sample size. However, there are many more rejections ($alpha = 0.05$) with the large sample size (61 for the small sample size vs 124 for the large).

[image]

A practical application of this is in p-hacking (which you should not do, even if people do it). Since you are more likely to see a large effect size when you reject with a small sample size, one research strategy could be to do experiments with small sample sizes and then present the ones that are significant, wowing your audiences with the large effect sizes. This is a terrible approach to science, and I bring it up as something to keep in mind might be done when we look at literature.

Comment: This is what Kjetil B Halvorsen means by "conditioned on being significant" in the comment to the original question. However, it is the case that the observed effect size is larger for the smaller sample size, whether the result is significant or not. This is attributable to the wider sampling distribution for a smaller sample size (standard error is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$).